# How to Loop Video after Another Transition Video?

Tags: ios, swiftui, avfoundation, avplayer

I have recently started touching swiftUI. For iOS16, I want to use AVFoundation to play the video for transition once and then loop the video for loop, but I don't know a good way to do it.

I would like to be able to choose to play the transition video with or without the loop video.

I asked ChatGPT3.0 and it returned the code below, but this did not work: after the video for transition and the video for loop plays once each, nothing is displayed.
I think it is under `NotificationCenter` that is not working, but I don't know how to change it.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class LoopingPlayerUIView: UIView {
    private let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer()
    private var playerLooper: AVPlayerLooper?

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    /// Depending on your video you can select a proper `videoGravity` property to fit better
    init(loopedVideoName: String,
         firstVideoName: String? = nil,
         player: AVQueuePlayer,
         videoGravity: AVLayerVideoGravity = .resizeAspectFill) {

        super.init(frame: .zero)

        // Load the looped video
        guard let loopedFileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: loopedVideoName, withExtension: "mp4") else { return }
        let loopedAsset = AVAsset(url: loopedFileUrl)
        let loopedItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: loopedAsset)

        // Set up the player with the looped video
        player.isMuted = true
        playerLayer.player = player
        playerLayer.videoGravity = videoGravity
        layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        // Play the first video once if provided
        if let firstVideoName = firstVideoName {
            guard let firstFileUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: firstVideoName, withExtension: "mp4") else { return }
            let firstAsset = AVAsset(url: firstFileUrl)
            let firstItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: firstAsset)

            playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: firstItem)

            // Observer for the end of the first video
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in
                // Switch to looped video and enable looping
                self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: loopedItem)
                self.playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: self.player, templateItem: loopedItem)
                self.player.play()
            }
        } else {
            // If firstVideoName is not provided, set up the looper for the looped video directly
            playerLooper = AVPlayerLooper(player: player, templateItem: loopedItem)
        }
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        playerLayer.frame = bounds
    }
}
```

Comment: There was a mistake. I want to choose to play the loop video with or without the "transition" video.